# Trying to enter an IP address into HTML and convert to URL using PHP

Tags: php, html, url

Maybe I'm crazy, but I've been trying this for a couple weeks now. I'm trying to run a PHP script that when executed through HTML it enters whatever IP address they entered through a form, will automatically either redirect the user with the IP in the address bar, or print the URL for them to copy and paste into their address bar. Basically I'd like the user to be directed to a link on my site, where they enter in their IP address, when they do so it redirects them to this URL so they can provision their IP phones.

`http://<Local IP Address>/admin/resync?http://voipcfg.planbcorp.com/initialize.xml`

where `<Local IP Address>` is replaced with the address they entered into the HTML form.

Is this possible?

My HTML doc looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone Provisioning Procedure</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="addIP.php">
<p><strong>Place Your IP Here:</strong><br/>
<input type="text" name="userip"/>
<p><input type="submit" value="Add my IP"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my PHP script looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone Provisioning Procedure</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Copy this or Select the URL to sync your Phone</h1>
<?php
$userip=$_POST['userip'];
$location = 'http://$userip/admin/resync?http://voipcfg.planbcorp.com/initialize.xml'
header('Location:' .$location);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The scheme in the URL is their own IP address, so how could they be redirected to your site?

Comment: Since there can be multiple sites under the same IP address, and what sites are on an IP address can change on a whim, I am pretty sure it is impossible to determine a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) from an IP

Comment: @NickJ Reverse DNS is often set up just fine.  The question is, do you want to rely on that?  Probably not, since the reverse DNS hostname is usually specific to the ISP.

Comment: Do each of your users have a webserver running on their phone?

Comment: Also how do they find their ip address, it may be possible but most users wont know how.

Comment: Ok I'll try and answer all of these, when they enter their IP into that URL it provisions their phone which is installed with our software, so it basically downloads our information to the IP of their phone.

Comment: We give them steps how to find the IP Address of their phone when we send them the setup guide. But after they set it up, we need to insert our code and software onto the phone for their location. That's was we need them to "Provision" the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the HTML, headers must be sent before the HTTP body:

```
<?php
$location = 'http://'
          . $_POST['userip'] .
          '/admin/resync?http://voipcfg.planbcorp.com/initialize.xml'
header('Location: ' .$location);
exit;
```

If this doesn't work yet, you need to URLencode the parameters (not sure tho):

```
<?php
$location = 'http://'
          . $_POST['userip']
          . '/admin/resync?'
          . urlencode('http://voipcfg.planbcorp.com/initialize.xml');
header('Location: ' .$location);
exit;
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly we edited at the same time I think. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I revised this now to include all the correct coding. I tested it and it should all work as intended.

```
    <?php
    // I would strip it of anything not a number and period since you are possibly outputting it to browser
    //  $userip =   preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/","",$_GET['userip']);
     $userip        =   preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/","",$_POST['userip']);


    // Use double quotes
    // Make sure this is a valid address
    $location   =   "http://$userip/admin/resync/?".urlencode('http://voipcfg.planbcorp.com/initialize.xml');
    // Check to see that the file exists in the url you are wanting to redirect to,
    // if xml file is in the location (there are probably better ways to check if a
    // file exists but I generally use file_get_contents for small files), then redirect
    if(file_get_contents($location))
        header('Location:' .$location);
    // If not a real location write out your page with a link
    else { ?><head>
<title>Phone Provisioning Procedure</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Copy this or Select the URL to sync your Phone</h1>
<p>URL: <?php echo $location; ?></p>
<a href="<?php echo $location; ?>">Click to go to the address</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well I'm going to try and test this out when I get back to my office tomorrow. thank you for all your help! I'll let you know if things don't or do work!

Comment: The key is that your $location is actually valid or else it will never redirect but rather display the html page.

Comment: So when I added the scripts to my main web page, they entered their IP hit submit and you get HTTP 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: And one other thing I just noticed is an error on my code. Should be: `file_get_contents(` not `get_file_contents(`. That will cause an error!! Sorry, my bad there! I always write that wrong!

Comment: Also `urlencode()` will help it not fail on reload. When I run the code it chugs for a second on checking if the page exists, but finally prints out properly.

Comment: Gonna Test it out and let you know!

Comment: Sorry was a long day! So the link worked, everything worked, it just didn't redirect, which Is fine, I heard somewhere that you can't redirect variable PHP URL's but so long as all they have to do is click the link then that's perfect!

Comment: So thank you for all your Help, I'm still learning PHP so much to know!

Comment: Are talking about `http://$userip/admin/resync/` vs a concrete link like `http://tester/admin/resync/`? If that is what you mean, that's not the case. That being said, if your link for sure is a legit forward, you can just skip the check part and force it to redirect but you will get a server error if it's not a real domain. Anyway, at the very least, in the end as long as something works...